# Programming Praxis weekly challenges

Tags: discussion, code-golf, code-challenge

This site (http://programmingpraxis.com) publishes every week very interesting code challenges, that could totally fit here.

Example: http://programmingpraxis.com/2014/07/25/number-words/ : that would be a perfect code-golf question.

Do you think we could, or should automatically publish those challenge here?

I emailed the webmaster to ask his approval

EDIT: here's the answer of the author:

> I wouldn't want to post complete exercises on
>   codegolf.stackexchange.com; I'm happy to keep my blog for that
>   purpose.
>
> If you wish, you are welcome to post pointers to my exercises. Perhaps
>   a short description of the problem, followed by a link back to my
>   page. Many of the exercises are simply too long for a Stack Exchange
>   posting, and the two-page exercise/solution format doesn't really fit.
>
> Are you sure my exercises fit your code-golf topic? Some of them do,
>   for instance the recent number-words exercise, but some of them would
>   make a bad fit; for instance, no one is interested in a code-golfed
>   version of elliptic-curve factorization.

So we can are allowed to use the puzzles that are suitable to code-golfing under those conditions. That's great. Do you guys agree with those conditions?

Answer (score 10):

I am the author of Programming Praxis.

I license my blog under a CC-BY-NC-SA license, which differs from the standard StackExchange license which is CC-BY-SA. StackExchange is a profit-making corporation, and I don't want my entire exercise copied here.

Of course, I am perfectly willing for folks here to use my exercises for their adventures in code golfing. So, feel free to copy enough of the exercise to state the problem, then attribute the exercise by putting a link back to the original exercise and suggested solution.

Does that work for everybody?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you obviously need his permission before posting, not least because everything posted on Stack Exchange is automatically licensed under CC BY-SA.

Still, he is a semi-regular contributor to Stack Overflow under the username [user448810](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448810), so he may see this. Eventually. (He and I both answer Scheme questions on SO, and we occasionally bump into each other.)

Comment: I had an answer, see OP

Comment: @xem He says you could post a "short description" of the puzzle (with a link), not the puzzle itself. I'm not sure how well that would work here. If ever the blog goes down, then the challenge/puzzle would be worthless forever. Challenges should be as self-contained as they possibly can be IMO.